# Bootstrap table double click row value

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to capture the row value after double click in bootstrap table. I can not do it and returns me undefined .

**My code**

```
$('#table').on('dbl-click-row.bs.table', function(field, value, row, $el) {
  if (value != "type") {
    alert($el.id + "-" + $el.name + "-" + $el.type);
  }
});
```

Comment: $(document).on('dblclick ', 'here go class or id element', function(field, value, row, $el)

Comment: thanks but $('#table').on('dbl-click-row.bs.table', 'table', function (field, value, row, $el) {
    if (value !="type"){
      alert($el.id+"-"+$el.key_fieldx+"-"+$el.type);
    }
  });
    not workink

Comment: the one you post is incorect look at my comment again or add html to your question so we can give you full code

Comment: Share an example of your table!

Comment: FYI: Anyone mistaking this for missing an event: https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/events/#ondblclickrow  `dbl-click-row.bs.table` is the event (not `dblclick`)

Answer (score 0):

this is my table  `

## Seznam prvků

```
                        <table  class="table-sm"
                        id="table"
                        data-search="true" 
                        data-filter-control="true"
                        data-visible-search="true"
                        data-pagination="true"
                        data-pagination-h-align="left"
                        data-pagination-detail-h-align="right"

                        data-show-refresh="true"
                        data-show-columns="true">


                        <thead class="thead-light">
                              <tr>
                                <th data-checkbox="true"></th>
                                <th data-field="id"  data-filter-control="input" data-switchable="false">ID</th> 
                                <th data-field="key_fieldx"  data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="input">Keyfieldx</th>
                                <th data-field="delka"  data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="input">length</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                          </table>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link you need to set one common `class` to get rows value

[Click me](https://jsfiddle.net/cvnkpaf0/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".jsTableRow").dblclick(function(){
  console.log($(this).html());
 alert($(this).html());
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">            
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="cursor:pointer;" title="double click to get data">
      <tr class="jsTableRow">
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="jsTableRow">
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="jsTableRow">
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```